# Citation XXX on page YYY undefined on input line ZZZ

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm working on my bachelor degree thesis on overleaf. I recently add a new reference in my bibliography and I cite it using the command \cite{...} (I'm using the biblatex package).

When I compile my work I encounter the warning: "Citation 'unit_2001' on page 9 undefined on input line 87" and in the output pdf the reference does not appear correctly.

Here's my .bib file

```
@article{unit_2001,
    title = {Associated production of Higgs and single top at hadron colliders},
    author = {F. Maltoni{,} K. Paul{,} T. Stelzer{,} and S. Willenbrock},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. D},
    doi = {doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.64.094023}, 
    year = 2001,
    month = {jun},
    volume = {64},
    number = {9},
    pages = {1},
}
@article{higgs_mechanism,  
    title = {The anatomy of electroweak symmetry breaking},  
    author = {Abdelhak Djouadi},  
    journal = {Phys. Rept.},
    doi = {10.1016/j.physrep.2007.10.004},
    year = 2008,
    month = {feb},
    volume = {457},
    number = {1-4},
    pages = {1--216},
}
@article{4top_observation,
    title={Observation of four-top-quark production in the multilepton final state with the ATLAS detector},
    author={ATLAS Collaboration},
    journal={Eur. Phys. J. C},
    doi={10.1140/epjc/s10052-023-11573-0},
    year=2023,
    month={jun},
    volume = {83},
    number = {496},
    pages = {1--216},
}
@misc{single_top,
      title={Higgs production in association with a single top quark at the LHC}, 
      author={Federico Demartin{,} Fabio Maltoni{,} Kentarou Mawatari and Marco Zaro},
    doi={10.48550/arXiv.1504.00611},
    month={apr},
      year={2015},
      eprint={1504.00611},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={hep-ph},
}
@article{4top2016,  
    title = {Probing Higgs width and top quark Yukawa coupling from $t\bar{t}H$ and $t\bar{t}t\bar{t}$ productions},
    author = {Qing-Hong Cao{,} Shao-Long Chen{,} and Yandong Liu},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. D},
    doi = {10.1103/physrevd.95.053004},  
    year = 2017,
    month = {mar},
    volume = {95},
    number = {5},
}
```

My main:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openright, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{changepage} %per cambiare i margini
\usepackage{graphicx, subcaption} %per allineare i plot orizzontalmente
%\usetikzlibrary{calc} % LATEX and plain TEX
%\usetikzlibrary[calc] % ConTEXt
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
%in order to reduce compilation time:
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\usepackage[figurename=FIG.]{caption}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE]{caption}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

%bibliografia (aggiornata)
%das ferbel
%quantum field theory for gifted amateaur
%articolo higgs mechanism
%prima pagina madgraph
%documentazione madgraph

\chapter{Introduction}

\input{introduction.tex}

\chapter{Come faccio i calcoli all'LHC}

MadGraph is an open source software written in Python, that aims at providing all the elements necessary for SM (Standard Model) and BSM (Beyond Standard Model) phenomenology, such as the computations of cross sections, the generation of hard events\footnote{Hard processes are those in which the momentum transfer is substantial with respect to the QCD scale.} and the automatical generating matrix element for High Energy Physics processes.



\chapter{Top-quark Yukawa coupling sensible processes}

\input{yt_processes.tex}

\chapter{Misura di 3+4 top semplificata}

\chapter{Unitarietà}

\input{unitarieta.tex}

\newpage

%\input{bibliography.tex}

%\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What I write

```
\subsection{$tH$ production}

The production of a Higgs boson plus a single top can be seen as a natural extension of a of the single-top production process, where a single top is radiated off the top or off the $W$-boson that mediates the bottom-to-top transition \cite{unit_2001}.
```

and what I see in the pdf

[image]

I don't know how to solve it
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: check the blg-files for errors, but the `F. Maltoni{,} K. Paul{,} T. Stelzer{,}`  looks definitively odd. What is the purpose?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I added the {,} in order to make the commas appear between the author names, now I remove them and it seems to work

Comment: authors should always be separated by `and` so `F. Maltoni and K. Paul and T. Stelzer and S. Willenbrock`. It is biblatex job to convert that then into commas (or something else).

Comment: You should be getting the following error message from biber: `ERROR - Name "F. Maltoni{,} K. Paul{,} T. Stelzer{,}" has too many commas, skipping entry 'unit_2001'.` Same for many other entries. Do take @UlrikeFischer's suggestion seriously.

Comment: Also, it's a mistake to write `month = {jun},`, `month = {feb},`, etc. Instead, do write `month = jun,`, `month = feb,`, etc.

Comment: And, since "ATLAS Corporation" a corporate author, do change `author  = {ATLAS Collaboration}` to `author  = {{ATLAS Collaboration}}`. This makes sure that biblatex/biber (a) won't interpret the author to have first name "Atlas" and surname "Corporation" and (b) will sort the entry under "A" for "Atlas" instead of under "C" for "Corporation".